# If cell value = Peter then stop and restart concatenation

Tags: excel, vba

I have this sheet.

Col A: Peter, James, George, etc. Sometimes in this long column there is the word Peter or Peter Smith or Peter Roy again.

Col C: Usually it is empty. Only whenever there is Peter or his variants in Col A, then there is a number at the corresponding cell of Col C (1, 4, 3, etc). For the rest, when there is James or George or another name, as mentioned, the corresponding cell C is empty.

Col B: here a normal formula would be needed like =CONCATENATE(A," ",C).

The problem is simple: as long as the script finds another neighbor Peter, we don't need cell B to be filled only by the value of A cell but we need it to be filled by the A value and the last corresponding Peter value.

An example image of what I need to achieve

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ALbq0.png)

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHCEe.png)

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use can solve it with the simple if statement in the formula:

1. In cell B1 use this formula: `=CONCAT(A1," ",C1)`
2. In cell B2 an downwoards use this formula: `=IF(C2="",CONCAT(A2,RIGHT(B1,LEN(B1)-SEARCH(" ",B1)+1)),CONCAT(A2," ",C2))`

Comment: Nice formula solution. Worth noting this will fail if the value in Column C is not a single digit/char. For instance, this will not suffice when `C1 =  11`. You would have to split the string on a space (and ensure you grab details after the right space if the name was `first last ##` format.

Comment: That's true - Solution is build upon the reference given by the author.

Comment: I have updated the formula that now include all the numbers/chars provided in column C

Comment: +1 I remodeled the formula a bit since I also needed to get the E data but your formula is excellent. Thank you!